# Is there any difference between running multithreaded program with and without debugger? Apart from obvious ones

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm doing a little project that tries to compare (simulate) Bluetooth Legacy Advertisement with Extended Advertisement. So I have two threads (one per device) and they are doing their tasks. I run the program normally and it's not working (kinda expected that) but when I run it with debugger it works. I have only one breakpoint and it's after any meaningful operations. So that is when my question arises. Is there any difference between running it with or without debugger.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA (newest version) and Java 1.8

Output when running normally (stopped by me):

```
343
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Output with debugger:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58359', transport: 'socket'
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
343
21 .. -39 
[21, ... -39]
DONE
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58359', transport: 'socket'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Code fragment with breakpoint

```
void secondaryListen() {
        if(!Simulation.World.channels[this.receivedAdvertisement.channel].empty) {
            SecondaryMessage currentMessage = (SecondaryMessage) Simulation.World.channels[this.receivedAdvertisement.channel].getPayload();
            for (byte b : currentMessage.content) {
                System.out.print(b +  " ");
                this.receivedData.add(b);
            }
            System.out.println();
            this.mode = Mode.SCAN;
            if(currentMessage.lastMessage) {
                this.mode = Mode.FINISHED; //BREAKPOINT ON THAT LINE
                System.out.println(this.receivedData.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all the answers in advance!

Comment: You likely have a race condition and are changing thread interleavings by debugging.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Turns out (like @PiRocks suggested) the problem was with race condition in other part of the code and it brought element of randomness to the program. Thanks for the answer